# metro style app text Box binding from source

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I am working on a textbox.
user writes to text box and searches. the selected search result(from list box) will be shown in text box again.

```
string selectedResult {get; set;}
selectedResult =  listBox.selectedValue.toString();
textBox.Text = selectedResult;
```

I want to bind the result to the text box. but I dont want selectedResult to change while texting. 
I tried one way binding but the selectedResult changes everytime the TextChanges.

any advices?

Comment: You need to use actual bindings in XAML, and you need to raise `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: @SLaks I did the actual binding in xaml.
<TextBox Text:"{Binding selectedResult}" .../>

Comment: And then you overwrote it in code.

Comment: I am sorry but you got it wrong. 
Instead of code I want to use binding but I only want to change the textbox.text when selectedResult Changes. I dont want selectedResult to change when textbox.text changes.

Comment: THen you want to make a one-way binding in XAML.

Comment: with one way binding changes the new text from XAML to .cs file. I want to do exactly opposite.